How to connect to my SQL server from Py script?
I am trying to connect to SQL server from Py script and I tried the same code of my jupyternotebook but the page shows blank after I import pyodbc. Is there any other way I connect to my SQL server from Pyscript?
Here is the code which I tried.
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Damp Brook</title>

    <!-- Recommended meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- PyScript CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.8.1/core.css">

    <!-- This script tag bootstraps PyScript -->
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.8.1/core.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="py" src="./main.py" config="./pyscript.toml" terminal></script>
</body>
</html>

main.py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server};"
            ""
            "")
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT  * FROM TestTable")
df = pd.DataFrame((tuple(t) for t in cursor))
print(df)

pyscript.toml
packages = ["pandas","pyodbc"]


You can't connect to any database server from a browser - unless it's a database that sues HTTP, not ODBC. Browsers don't allow database connections. Only HTTP calls are possible. Besides, the Python code is wrong.  Pandas has read_sql to read data from databases. read_sql requires sqlalchemy. This works fine in Jupyter Notebooks, because the code itself runs on the server (or the application hosting Jupyter like VS Code), not the web page

Python code is perfectly correct.I can send you a screen shot with output if you want.Yes there are other ways as well.

If it did, why did you post a question? Just because it works locally doesn't mean it can run in a browser. Even if the connection string wasn't broken, just because something works doesn't mean it's correct. What you posted has to load everything in memory before Pandas has a chance to start loading the data, something avoided with read_sql. You also lose all the information (like schema) that read_sql retrieves from the database results. For lots of rows, you lose the ability to load data in batches. You have to manually convert non-Python types like decimal to floats.

Thank you for the information.I think we all write questions to learn from each other and I learned something new which I didn't knew before.I wanted to know if there is a possibility that I can make it run on browser that's the reason I posted the question.

Connecting directly to a SQL Server using pyodbc from a PyScript application is not feasible due to several limitations:
Pyodbc Compatibility: pyodbc is a C extension module that requires native system libraries. PyScript runs in the browser using Pyodide, which supports only pure Python packages or those specifically compiled for WebAssembly. pyodbc is not available in Pyodide's package repository and cannot be used in the browser environment.
Browser Limitations: Browsers do not support the necessary network protocols and sockets required to establish a direct connection to a SQL Server. Security restrictions prevent browsers from opening arbitrary network connections to protect users from malicious activities.
Security Concerns: Even if it were technically possible, exposing your database directly to client-side applications would pose significant security risks. It could allow unauthorized access to your database, leading to data breaches.

This is an AI-generated answer that's only 66% wrong.. The only real answer is that browsers can't connect to databases with ODBC. Everything else is noise and actually wrong - people have created WASM versions of SQLite. C code has been compiled to WASM.
